# libgdx array list contains elements of all states

Tags: java, arrays, state

Im using libGDX and have an array list like this:

```
public final List<Element1> element1s;
```

Then I added elements like this:

```
    Element1 element1 = new Element1(384, 960);
    element1s.add(element1);

    Element1 element2 = new Element1(384 + 122, 960 - 24);
    element1s.add(element2);
```

the Element1's class gives each element a random state:

```
// STATE
public int ELEMENT1_STATE1_GREEN = 0;
public int ELEMENT1_STATE1_BLUE = 1;
public int ELEMENT1_STATE1_PINK = 2;
public int ELEMENT1_STATE1_YELLOW = 3;
public int ELEMENT1_STATE1_RED = 4;
public int ELEMENT1_STATE1_ORANGE = 5;
public int ELEMENT1_STATE1_PURPLE = 6;
public int ELEMENT1_STATE1_WHITE = 7;

public Element1(float x, float y) {
    super(x, y, ELEMENT1_WIDTH, ELEMENT1_HEIGHT);
    state1 = rand.nextInt(8);
}
```

Now I want to check if the elements in the list contains all ints of state1 (from 0 to 7)...to be exact if (coincidentally) the list contains an element1 with the state1 = 0, an element1 with the state1 = 1, an element1 with the state1 = 2...and so on till element1 with state1 = 7...so that there arent two elements with the same state1. How should I do that?

Comment: There are probably dozens of ways to do this. But my question is, what will you do with the list if you find out that it does or doesn't contain at least one of each type? If the answer is that you will rebuild the list, maybe you should change your method of creating the list so it doesn't produce an unacceptable list. Also, you didn't mention how many elements are in the list, which is why I didn't post any solutions. I'm unclear on whether it has exactly 8 items, or greater than 8, and if you are only wanting to check if *at least* one of each type is represented.

Comment: First thanks for the reply...And sorry my question was a bit unclear I guess! Im trying to use this code for a game. There are 16 elements in the list! If I shoot an element it will randomly change its state...but there always have to be all states at the same time while the game is running...so I have to check if a shot element can change its state randomly, because the other elements repesent all states from 0 to 7, or if it has to change to a state, the other elements dont represent at that time..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but this is how I would probably do it, assuming your goal is to determine if all integers from 0-7 are represented. I initially thought, create 8 booleans set to false, and then loop through the list and mark them true as each of the integers are found. But this can be done with a lot less typing if you use bitwise operations on a single int.

```
private boolean doesElement1ListRepresentAllState1Types(List<Element1> list){
    int representedInts = 0;
    for (Element1 element : list)
        representedInts |= (1 << element.state1);
    return representedInts == Integer.parseInt("11111111", 2);
}
```

Comment: Hey there...Thanks for your answer...I will try your suggestion! Many thanks!